# How to make and install the image of my own Ubuntu 16.04 installation with Docker on a remote server

Tags: docker, clone, disk-image, debootstrap

I'm going to hire some space on a remote linux workstation equipped with a Geforce GTX 1080 ti because I want to run there this deep learning repository :

https://github.com/CMU-Perceptual-Computing-Lab/MonocularTotalCapture

It requires Ubuntu 16.04 and Cuda 9 to run and my graphic card (Geforce RTX 2080 ti) does not support it. I have also another computer with a Geforce 1060. I have installed the repo on that computer,but when I run it It always give this error to me :

```
./openpose/build/examples/openpose/openpose.bin --face --hand --image_dir ./example_dance/raw_image --write_json example_dance/openpose_result --render_pose 0 --display 0 -model_pose BODY_25 -Starting OpenPose demo...Configuring OpenPose...Starting thread(s)...Auto-detecting all available GPUs... Detected 1 GPU(s), using 1 of them starting at GPU 0.F0322 22:31:40.377177 10803 syncedmem.cpp:71] Check failed: error == cudaSuccess (2 vs. 0)  out of memory

*** Check failure stack trace: ***    @     0x7f9f2800e5cd  google::LogMessage::Fail()    @
```

I suppose that that PC is not enough powerful to run the repository. I've contacted this company :

https://www.leadergpu.com/

they told me that I should "install my image to our server using docker container". They also say that they haven't a specific tutorial that I can follow to learn how to do that. Since I'm not a pro,I'm an hobbyst,I'm here to ask if someone has some specific tutorial to do what I want. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is off in Docker land but I'm going to try and do my best to help.

You'll probably need to create an account on the Docker Hub in order to get the image onto their server(s).

Your best friend in this endeavor is google because you're going to need to learn how to create a Dockerfile.

You're going to need to create a Dockerfile and then install the necessary items you need into that image.i.e. MonocularTotalCapture

This is a rough framework of what you're going to need with a lot missing, but hopefully you get the idea, you have to step through the typical installation process but instead of running the commands on your machine, they are docker commands.

From https://github.com/CMU-Perceptual-Computing-Lab/MonocularTotalCapture you need to go through and add all of the dependencies and then walk through all of the installation steps.

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
RUN apt update \
    && apt install -y ffmpeg \
    && apt install -y python3.5 \
    && apt install -y pip3 \
    && apt install -y git

RUN git clone "https://github.com/CMU-Perceptual-Computing-Lab/MonocularTotalCapture.git"
```

As a note, this is not necessarily going to be an easy process it is doable and you're going to learn a lot in the process.

EDIT: You might not need to start with a bare Ubuntu image. https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker Looks like nvidia as an ubuntu base image with their drivers which is probably an even better starting point as you won't need to manually install the drivers during the install process.

Comment: I've already been able to make work the Monocular Total Capture repository. But I'm not able to repeat all the steps because I've been lucky. I gone through trial and errors. For this reason I want to clone my existing ubuntu installation and make a docker image of everything that's inside of it.

Comment: As far as I know you can't clone an ubuntu installation into a docker image. The point of Docker is to make a process repeatable and consistent. I built a modded minecraft image and it took me a couple of days troubleshooting wise to get it working. You troubleshoot it the same way, it's just in a docker container. You find an issue, figure out a solution, stop the container, change the dockerfile, rebuild the image from your updated dockerfile, start up the container and see what else breaks.

Comment: is this tutorial good ? https://juliensalinas.com/en/dockerize-whole-linux-server/

Comment: That looks like a good starting place. Bret Fisher also has some online resources and is one of the Docker Captains. Another great source for information is docs.docker.com. Docker has a very robust documentation set.

Comment: usually I skip the written documentation set. I haven't the patience nor the knowledge to read everything and understand only what I really need to know. I'm looking for specific tutorial focused on what I should do. I created the post in more than 1 place,including the docker forum,but right now I didn't get any reply. Maybe this is caused by the corona virus ? It's odd because people can't go out of home,should be more focused on the internet related things.